# the power series converges in compact convergence topology

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

> > Consider the sequence of functions $f_{n}: (-1,1) \rightarrow R$ defined by:$$f_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{kx^{k}}$$
> >     
> > a) Prove that $(f_{n})$ converges in the topology of compact convergence, conclude that the limit function is continuous
> >     
> > b)Show that $(f_{n})$ does not converge in the uniform topology.

I'm learning function space in topology and find it hard to imagine, especially the compact convergence topology. I got stuck in this problem

As I know, we don't even have the clear formula for the function that this sequence converges to, so how can we prove that sequence converges at all. One more thing, is there other ways to prove a sequence of functions converges in compact convergence topology except proving it converges uniformly in every compact subspace, cause in some spaces, we don't know all their compact subspaces

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can actually determine what the limit has to be, if it exists. The series $\sum_{k\ge 1}kx^k$ is absolutely convergent for $|x|<1$. We know that $$\sum_{k\ge 0}x^k=\frac1{1-x}$$ for $|x|<1$; taking the derivative and multiplying by $x$ yields $$\sum_{k\ge 1}kx^k=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\;,$$ which is the only reasonable candidate for the limit of the sequence $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$.

Note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k=\sum_{k\ge 1}kx^k-\sum_{k\ge n+1}kx^k\;,$$

and you can use the same trick to get a closed form for $\sum_{k\ge n+1}kx^k$, so you can actually get an explicit formula for each $f_n$.

Finally, every compact subset of $(-1,1)$ is contained in a closed interval $[-a,a]$ with $0<a<1$, so you need only look at these intervals.

Comment: Your last point is simple but the key of the problem. Thanks so much...

Comment: Oh, what about the (b) problem. Can you prove that too?

Comment: @leducquang: Let $\epsilon>0$ and $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}. For each $x\in[0,1)$ let $n_\epsilon(x)$ be the smallest $n$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$. Prove that $n_\epsilon\to\infty$ as $x\to 1^-$. The point is that when $x$ is close to $0$, $f_n(x)$ converges very rapidly to $f(x)$, but when $x$ is close to $1$, the convergence of $f_n(x)$ to $f(x)$ is much slower.

Comment: Oh, the mathJava is broken. Can you fix it, cause it make a little difficult to read...Thanks

Comment: @leducquang: It’s too late to fix it, but I type it again. For each $x\in[0,1)$ let $n_\epsilon(x)$ be the smallest $n$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$. Prove that $n_\epsilon(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to 1^-$. The point is that when $x$ is close to $0$, $f_n(x)$ converges very rapidly to $f(x)$, but when $x$ is close to $1$, the convergence of $f_n(x)$ is much slower. And it gets slower fast enough to keep the overall convergence from being uniform.

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\iff F'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n kx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n kx^k-\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n kx^k-F(x)$$ $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n kx^k=F(x)+F'(x)=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}+\left(\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\right)_x'=\ldots$$

Comment: I don't think it's right when using calculus here,cause the topology is compact convergence, not uniform...

Comment: The formulas are correct. Perhaps you meant to say they are not helpful ? Either way, I meant to address the complaint you expressed in your post, about not knowing whether or not the function possesses a closed form expression. More information on this topic can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: Oh, I got what you mean. I think that's your solution and it makes me feel like not enough. Sorry and thanks for your help...